# angularjs: dynamic ngResource URL depending on value from a controller

Tags: angularjs, url, dynamic, service, controller

i'm new to angularjs and couldn't find an answer to my question anywhere.
So, i have a service that gets called into a controller.
What i would like to do is to get a particular value from this controller and construct another service url with it.

Here is an example:

```
angular.module('myApp')

  .factory('MyFirstService' function($resource){
    return $resource ('api/data/:id', { id: '@_id'}, { update: { method: 'PUT'}});
  })
  .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, MyFirstService){
    $scope.data = MyFirstService.get({id: $stateParams.id});

    var dataSpecificValue = $scope.data.SpecificValue;

  })
  .factory('MySecondService', function($resource){
    var SpecificValue = dataSpecificValue;
    return $resource('api/' + SpecificValue + '/:id', { id: '@_id'}, { update: { method: 'PUT'}});
  });
```

It seems that i should inject "myCtrl" controller into 'MySecondService' factory to retrieve the value of 'SpecificValue', but it would be a weird practice, no?

Comment: You should call `MySecondService` with `dataSpecificValue` as param.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be injecting a controller into a service.  You should create a setter method in your factory where from your controller, you can set the variable.  I would do so like the following:

```
angular.module('myApp')

 .factory('MyFirstService' function($resource){
    return $resource ('api/data/:id', { id: '@_id'}, { update: { method: 'PUT'}});
 })

 .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, MyFirstService, MySecondService){
    $scope.data = MyFirstService.get({id: $stateParams.id});

    MySecondService.setterMethod($scope.data.SpecificValue);

 })

 .factory('MySecondService', function($resource){

    var SpecificValue;
     var setterMethod = function(dataSpecificValue){
         SpecificValue = dataSpecificValue;
     }

     var otherFunction = function(){
        $resource('api/' + SpecificValue + '/:id', { id: '@_id'}, { update: { method: 'PUT'}});
     }

     return {
        setterMethod : setterMethod,
        otherFunction : otherFunction
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`specificValue` is not different from `id`:

```
angular.module('myApp')

  .factory('MyFirstService' function($resource){
    return $resource ('api/data/:id', { id: '@_id'}, { update: { method: 'PUT'}});
  })
  .factory('MySecondService', function($resource){
    return $resource('api/:specificValue/:id', {id: '@_id'}, { update: { method: 'PUT'}});
  })
  .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, MyFirstService, MySecondService){
    $scope.data = MyFirstService.get({id: $stateParams.id});
    var dataSpecificValue = $scope.data.SpecificValue;
    var secondValue = MySecondService.get({specificValue: dataSpecificValue, id: $stateParams.id});
  });
```